# How to ignore specific word from a group of words in a cell and send one email to group of people?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. I am working hard and learning it but there is a point where I am stuck now. If someone please help me out then I shall be grateful.
I have a drop down list in excel like

```
 Sales/Acquisition Manager (AM)         Alina (Alina@yahoo.com)
 Acquisition Project Manager (APM)      Benny(Benny@yahoo.com)
 Manufacturing                          Julia(Julia@yahoo.com)
 Application                            please select (drop down list so I can choose)
 AE external sensor responsible         please select (Drop down list so I can choose)
```

I have made a separate row (row 59 Col A) where I have combined these values from the above rows.

I have to make a macro to send 1 email to these multiple people. I have written a code for sending email but I am stuck at another point. I have written code which replaces the words `please select` with “ ” whenever it finds it in row 59 but unfortunately that code changes the line permanently which I don’t want.

What I want is that whenever it finds the words `please select` in a row it just ignores it and and also doesn't change the format of cell. Means when I again change some new value by drop down list so it got changed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim the_string As String
  the_string = Sheets("Schedule_team").Range("A59")
  the_string = Replace(the_string, "please select", " ")

  Sheets("Schedule_team").Range("A59") = the_string

  MsgBox (Sheets("Schedule_team").Range("A59"))

  Dim i As Integer, Mail_Object, Email_Subject, o As Variant, lr As Long, x As Variant

  Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  x = Cells (59, 1).Value
  With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
    ' .Subject = Range("B1").Value
      .To = x
    ' .Body = Range("B2").Value
    ' .Send
      .display 'disable display and enable send to send automatically
  End With

  MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", 64
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Set Mail_Object = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your formula in `A59`?  You can change the formula to ignore `please select` or you can copy the value of the cell into VBA and run the replace on the variable instead of the actual cell value.

Comment: You use both the_string and x for A59...any reason?

Comment: @Rdster
Thank you very much. issued is solved...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull the contents of A59 into the string, replace as needed, then just use that string instead of copying it back to the sheet.

*Untested, just used your code*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim Mail_Object as Object
  Dim the_string As String

  the_string = Sheets("Schedule_team").Range("A59")
  the_string = Replace(the_string, "please select", " ")

  Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
    ' .Subject = Range("B1")
    .To = the_string
    ' .Body = Range("B2")
    ' .Send
    .Display 'disable display and enable send to send automatically
  End With

  MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", 64
End Sub
```